# Which html-elements can contain elements of same kind?

Tags: html, dom

**My question is:**

Which html elements can contain other elements with the same tag name. (Like a `<div>` inside another `<div>` which is allowed.) And which html-elements (among them who are able to have content) are not allowed to have elements with the same tag name among it's descendants. (Like `<p>` inside another `<p>` which is not allowed.)

---

**background**

I want to write an html-parser (a lexer to be more precise) to be able to automatically process html-documents that my script reads from internet. I know there are out-of-the-box parsers (and lexers) for almost every language, but I want to try to write my own.

When doing so, there is the problem to handle malformed html, and one of the problems is to close html-elements that have a valid opening-tag, but no close-tag. So you have to make an educated guess where a `<div>` without matching `</div>` ends, and where a `<p>` without matching `</p>` has it's end.

You can split html-elements into three classes:

1. Elements that per definition can't have any content, like `<img>` or `<br>`
2. Elements that can contain descendants of the same type (`<div>` in `<div>` is allowed)
3. Elements that can have content, but not of the same element-type (`<p>` can contain text, `<a>` and many other elements, but `<p>` in `<p>` is not allowed)

Here I'm not interested in the "void elements" as described in 1 because those elements can't have close tags (and so, they never will miss closing tags).

When it comes to create closing tags that was missing, types 2 and 3 must be handled differently.

If your receive a document that contains this:

```
<body> a <div> b <div> c </body>
```

most browser will internally transform it into something like this:

```
<body>
    a
    <div>
        b
        <div>
            c
        </div> <!-- inserted -->
    </div> <!-- inserted -->
</body>
```

All divs are closed at the same point, just before the first existing non-div-closing-tag that, together with its matching opening-tag, embraces the div-tags who's closing tags are missing. This algorithm gives nested elements where each unclosed element becomes the child of its previous unclosed fellow.

But if you get this

```
<body> a <p> b <p> c </body>
```

most browsers will convert it into this:

```
<body>
    a
    <p>
        b
    </p> <!-- inserted -->
    <p>
        c
    </p> <!-- inserted -->
</body>
```

In this case one p-element is closed when the next p-element begins, or when a non-p-closing-tag is detected, who's opening-partner lays before the opening p-tag who's closing tag is missing. This algorithm does not produce nested elements of the same type, but produces siblings who are children of the same parent.

And to be able to decide which algorithm should be used to close elements, I need to know which elements belong to which class.

Comment: The spec is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/

Comment: "In this case one p-element is closed when the next p-element begins, or when a non-p-closing-tag is detected, who's opening-partner lays before the opening p-tag who's closing tag is missing" — The p element gets closed when either there is an end tag for it, or there it a start tag for elements that cannot be contained within a p element. "An end tag or another p start tag" isn't enough of a rule to write a parser with.

Comment: HTML is a whole grammar, so it's more complicated than these 3 classes. If you are simplifying your model by ignoring this point (which is fine for educational purposes), I don't really what you gain by caring about which elements can contain themselves. e.g. if your model ignores that `td` must be inside `tr`, why should it care that `div` can be inside another `div`?